# convert spring boot tomcat azure k8s deployment to standalone application

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-aks

I have created an azure devops project for java , spring boot and kubernetes as a way to learn about the azure technology set. It does work , the simple spring boot web application is deployed and runs and is rebuilt if I make code changes.

However the spring boot application uses a very old version of spring 1.5.7.RELEASE and it is deployed in a tomcat server in k8s.

I am looking for some guidance on how to run it as a standalone spring boot version 2 application in kubernetes. My attempts so far have resulted in the deployment timing out after 15 minutes in the Helm Upgrade step.

The existing docker file

```
FROM maven:3.5.2-jdk-8 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN mvn package

FROM tomcat:8
RUN rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT
COPY --from=build-env /app/target/*.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war
```

How to change the dockerfile to build the image of a standalone spring boot app?

I changed the pom to generate a jar file, then modified the docker file to this:

```
FROM maven:3.5.2-jdk-8 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN mvn package

FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
COPY --from=build-env  /app/target/ROOT.jar .
RUN ls -la
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","ROOT.jar"]
```

This builds, see output from the log for 'Build an image' step

```
...
2019-06-25T23:33:38.0841365Z Step 9/20 : COPY --from=build-env  /app/target/ROOT.jar .
2019-06-25T23:33:41.4839851Z  ---> b478fb8867e6
2019-06-25T23:33:41.4841124Z Step 10/20 : RUN ls -la
2019-06-25T23:33:41.6653383Z  ---> Running in 4618c503ac5c
2019-06-25T23:33:42.2022890Z total 50156
2019-06-25T23:33:42.2026590Z drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Jun 25 23:33 .
2019-06-25T23:33:42.2026975Z drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Jun 25 23:33 ..
2019-06-25T23:33:42.2027267Z -rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root             0 Jun 25 23:33 .dockerenv
2019-06-25T23:33:42.2027608Z -rw-r--r--    1 root     root      51290350 Jun 25 23:33 ROOT.jar
2019-06-25T23:33:42.2027889Z drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 May  9 20:49 bin
2019-06-25T23:33:42.2028188Z drwxr-xr-x    5 root     root           340 Jun 25 23:33 dev
2019-06-25T23:33:42.2028467Z drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Jun 25 23:33 etc
2019-06-25T23:33:42.2028765Z drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 May  9 20:49 home
2019-06-25T23:33:42.2029376Z drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 May 11 01:32 lib
2019-06-25T23:33:42.2029682Z drwxr-xr-x    5 root     root          4096 May  9 20:49 media
2019-06-25T23:33:42.2029961Z drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 May  9 20:49 mnt
2019-06-25T23:33:42.2030257Z drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 May  9 20:49 opt
2019-06-25T23:33:42.2030537Z dr-xr-xr-x  135 root     root             0 Jun 25 23:33 proc
2019-06-25T23:33:42.2030937Z drwx------    2 root     root          4096 May  9 20:49 root
2019-06-25T23:33:42.2031214Z drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 May  9 20:49 run
2019-06-25T23:33:42.2031523Z drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 May  9 20:49 sbin
2019-06-25T23:33:42.2031797Z drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 May  9 20:49 srv
2019-06-25T23:33:42.2032254Z dr-xr-xr-x   12 root     root             0 Jun 25 23:33 sys
2019-06-25T23:33:42.2032355Z drwxrwxrwt    2 root     root          4096 May  9 20:49 tmp
2019-06-25T23:33:42.2032656Z drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 May 11 01:32 usr
2019-06-25T23:33:42.2032945Z drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 May  9 20:49 var
2019-06-25T23:33:43.0909881Z Removing intermediate container 4618c503ac5c
2019-06-25T23:33:43.0911258Z  ---> 0d824ce4ae62
2019-06-25T23:33:43.0911852Z Step 11/20 : ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","ROOT.jar"]
2019-06-25T23:33:43.2880002Z  ---> Running in bba9345678be
...
```

The build completes but deployment fails in the Helm Upgrade step, timing out after 15 minutes. This is the log

```
2019-06-25T23:38:06.6438602Z ##[section]Starting: Helm upgrade
2019-06-25T23:38:06.6444317Z ==============================================================================
2019-06-25T23:38:06.6444448Z Task         : Package and deploy Helm charts
2019-06-25T23:38:06.6444571Z Description  : Deploy, configure, update a Kubernetes cluster in Azure Container Service by running helm commands
2019-06-25T23:38:06.6444648Z Version      : 0.153.0
2019-06-25T23:38:06.6444927Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2019-06-25T23:38:06.6445006Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/helm-deploy
2019-06-25T23:38:06.6445300Z ==============================================================================
2019-06-25T23:38:09.1285973Z [command]/opt/hostedtoolcache/helm/2.14.1/x64/linux-amd64/helm upgrade --tiller-namespace dev2134 --namespace dev2134 --install --force --wait --set image.repository=stephenacr.azurecr.io/stephene991 --set image.tag=20 --set applicationInsights.InstrumentationKey=643a47f5-58bd-4012-afea-b3c943bc33ce --set imagePullSecrets={stephendockerauth} --timeout 900 azuredevops /home/vsts/work/r1/a/Drop/drop/sampleapp-v0.2.0.tgz
2019-06-25T23:53:13.7882713Z UPGRADE FAILED
2019-06-25T23:53:13.7883396Z Error: timed out waiting for the condition
2019-06-25T23:53:13.7885043Z Error: UPGRADE FAILED: timed out waiting for the condition
2019-06-25T23:53:13.7967270Z ##[error]Error: UPGRADE FAILED: timed out waiting for the condition

2019-06-25T23:53:13.7976964Z ##[section]Finishing: Helm upgrade
```

Comment: I did confirm that the Dockerfile worked and confirmed that I could deploy the application using the Helm chart to minikube.

Comment: I did raise a support request with Microsoft but they have been unable to solve it

Answer (score 0):

I have had another look at this as I now am more familiar with all the technologies, and I have located the problem.

The helm upgrade statement is timing out waiting for the newly deployed pod to become live but this doesn’t happen because the k8s liveness probe defined for the pod is not working. This can be seen with this command :

```
kubectl get po  -n dev5998 -w
NAME                           READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
sampleapp-86869d4d54-nzd9f     0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   17         48m
sampleapp-c8f84c857-phrrt      1/1     Running            0          1h
sampleapp-c8f84c857-rmq8w      1/1     Running            0          1h
tiller-deploy-79f84d5f-4r86q   1/1     Running            0          2h
```

The new pod is repeatedly restarted then killed. It seems to repeat forever or until another deployment is run.

In the log for the pod

```
kubectl describe po sampleapp-86869d4d54-nzd9f -n dev5998
Events:
  Type     Reason                 Age                    From                               Message
  ----     ------                 ----                   ----                               -------
  Normal   Scheduled              39m                    default-scheduler                  Successfully assigned sampleapp-86869d4d54-nzd9f to aks-agentpool-24470557-1
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  39m                    kubelet, aks-agentpool-24470557-1  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "default-token-v72n5"
  Normal   Pulling                39m                    kubelet, aks-agentpool-24470557-1  pulling image "devopssampleacreg.azurecr.io/devopssamplec538:52"
  Normal   Pulled                 39m                    kubelet, aks-agentpool-24470557-1  Successfully pulled image "devopssampleacreg.azurecr.io/devopssamplec538:52"
  Normal   Created                37m (x3 over 39m)      kubelet, aks-agentpool-24470557-1  Created container
  Normal   Started                37m (x3 over 39m)      kubelet, aks-agentpool-24470557-1  Started container
  Normal   Killing                37m (x2 over 38m)      kubelet, aks-agentpool-24470557-1  Killing container with id docker://sampleapp:Container failed liveness probe.. Container will be killed and recreated.
  Warning  Unhealthy              36m (x6 over 38m)      kubelet, aks-agentpool-24470557-1  Liveness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 404
  Warning  Unhealthy              34m (x12 over 38m)     kubelet, aks-agentpool-24470557-1  Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 404
  Normal   Pulled                 9m25s (x12 over 38m)   kubelet, aks-agentpool-24470557-1  Container image "devopssampleacreg.azurecr.io/devopssamplec538:52" already present on machine
  Warning  BackOff                4m10s (x112 over 34m)  kubelet, aks-agentpool-24470557-1  Back-off restarting failed container
```

So there must be a difference in what urls are delivered by the application depending on how it is deployed, tomcat or standalone. Which now seems obvious.